# Angular7 - Error working with multiple questions in handling radio control in forms

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7, angular-forms

I'm trying to handle multiple mcq based questions in reactive angular form. But the issue is that when i click option from one question, the selection from other question dissappears. I know there is something to be fixed with id's and values and use question.problem in them also... but don't know exactly how.

here is the code.......
**HTML**

```html
<div class="mcq test" *ngFor="let mcq of mcqs">
<form (submit)="mcqSubmit($event)" [formGroup]="mcqForm" class=" mt-5 mb-4">
<h3 class="mt-3 p-3 font-weight-bold"><u>{{mcq.title}}</u></h3>
    <div class="questions" *ngFor="let question of mcq.questions">
        <div class="text-center justify-content-center assignment-item mb-4" >
            <h4 class="mt-3 mb-3" >{{question.problem}}</h4>

                <div *ngFor="let solution of question.solutions; let i = index" class="d-inline p-3 mr-3 ml-3">

                        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="radio{{i}}" [value]=solution.option formControlName="choice">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        <label for="radio{{i}}" class="mcq-item">  
                        {{i+1 +'.'+ solution.option | titlecase}}
                    </label>
                    <br *ngIf="(i+1)%2==0 then ifblock">
                    <ng-template #ifblock>
                            <br>
                    </ng-template>
                </div>


        </div>

    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary d-block mx-auto mt-4" value="Submit" >
            </form>
</div>
```

and here is **angular part**.

````js
this.mcqForm = this.fb.group({
    choice: ['',Validators.required]
}); ```
````

Comment: can you show the mock data of mcqs?

Comment: [{title: "sample mcq test", questions: [,…]}]
0: {title: "sample mcq test", questions: [,…]}
questions: [,…]
0: {marks: 3, problem: "what is your age", solutions: [{option: "22"}, {option: "21"}, {option: "20"}]}
marks: 3
problem: "what is your age"
solutions: [{option: "22"}, {option: "21"}, {option: "20"}]
1: {marks: 6, problem: "what is your name",…}
marks: 6
problem: "what is your name"
solutions: [{option: "sachin"}, {option: "ravinder"}, {option: "subham"}, {option: "namrta"}]
title: "sample mcq test"

Comment: here is the data..

Answer (score 0):

If we simplify this part of the code

```
<form (submit)="mcqSubmit($event)" [formGroup]="mcqForm">
<div class="questions" *ngFor="let question of mcq.questions">
        <div class="text-center justify-content-center assignment-item mb-4" >
            <h4 class="mt-3 mb-3" >{{question.problem}}</h4>

                <div *ngFor="let solution of question.solutions; let i = index" class="d-inline p-3 mr-3 ml-3">

                        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="radio{{i}}" [value]=solution.option formControlName="choice">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        <label for="radio{{i}}" class="mcq-item">  
                        {{i+1 +'.'+ solution.option | titlecase}}
                    </label>
                    <br *ngIf="(i+1)%2==0 then ifblock">
                    <ng-template #ifblock>
                            <br>
                    </ng-template>
                </div>


        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

We will see

```
<form (submit)="mcqSubmit($event)" [formGroup]="mcqForm" class=" mt-5 mb-4">    <div *ngFor="let question of mcq.questions">
     <h4>{{question.problem}}</h4>
       <div *ngFor="let solution of question.solutions; let i = index">
         <input type="radio" name="choice" id="radio{{i}}" [value]=solution.option formControlName="choice">
        <label for="radio{{i}}" class="mcq-item">  
                            {{i+1 +'.'+ solution.option | titlecase}}
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And I hope you can see that you are rendering input boxes with the same form-control under the same form group.

I would suggest you use [form array](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray).